# SQL Query not working correctly on where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Update:** Alright, so `$id` was a string for some reason while I was expecting an int. I've changed by code to:

```
$id = (int) $id;
      $query = "SELECT funding_opportunities.id
FROM funding_opportunities
  JOIN funders ON funding_opportunities.funder = funders.id
WHERE funders.id='$id'";
```

With `var_dump($id)` returning `int(1)` and echoing the query returning

```
SELECT funding_opportunities.id FROM funding_opportunities JOIN funders ON funding_opportunities.funder = funders.id WHERE funders.id='1'
```

for the query

```
$id = (int) $id;
      $query = "SELECT funding_opportunities.id
FROM funding_opportunities
  JOIN funders ON funding_opportunities.funder = funders.id
WHERE funders.id='$id'";
        var_dump($id);
echo $query;
```

But I still get the same error

I have the following SQL query I'm trying to execute from my PHP file:

```
"SELECT funding_opportunities.id 
FROM funding_opportunities 
  JOIN funders ON funding_opportunities.funder = funders.id 
WHERE funders.id=".$id
```

Which returns the following error:

> **Error Number: 1064** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '**1**' at line **1**

I have done the following:

Replaced `$id` with `1` as an integer, to check if there was something unforseen in my variable, same error.

Used several online SQL syntax checker tools, nothing detected.

Re-built the query from PhpMyAdmin, values retrieved correctly.

Can anybody spot the error?

Comment: It's the ".$id part that's wrong. No terminating "?

Comment: can you please tell the table structure i.e. comman col

Comment: @jarlh no, that's not that, he just concated query with `$id` there is no need to terminate it by ". @max005 first of all, don't concat your query with variables, it's insecure, imagine that your `$id` is a string like this `1;drop database;`. Try to use pdo and param binding. Second, can you write `var_dump($id)` here ?

Comment: Can you show the php file?

Comment: max0005  guy ... is making fun of us ...... this post doesn't appear any error

Answer (score 0):

Try this if `ID` is int-

```
WHERE funders.id='$id'"
```

If `ID` is character-

```
WHERE funders.id=\"".$id."\""
```

Comment: I've tried it, and by echoing the query I get: SELECT funding_opportunities.id FROM funding_opportunities JOIN funders ON funding_opportunities.funder = funders.id WHERE funders.id='1' However, the same error remains?

Comment: Kindly put your table structure. Check database which you are connecting through PHP is same as PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Please check the data-type and values of both id are same when you user join on two column.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the ID is comprised of, you may need single quotes around it to validate to a string value, i.e.:

```
"SELECT funding_opportunities.id 
FROM funding_opportunities 
JOIN funders 
ON funding_opportunities.funder = funders.id
WHERE funders.id= '".$id."'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query. You are not joining $id to query part

```
"SELECT funding_opportunities.id FROM funding_opportunities JOIN funders ON funding_opportunities.funder = funders.id WHERE funders.id='".$id."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use query like this

```
"SELECT funding_opportunities.id 
FROM funding_opportunities 
JOIN funders ON funding_opportunities.funder = funders.id 
WHERE funders.id='".$id."' "
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below sql

```
"SELECT funding_opportunities.id 
FROM   funding_opportunities 
JOIN   funders 
ON     funding_opportunities.funder = funders.id 
WHERE  funders.id='".$id."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"SELECT funding_opportunities.id 
FROM funding_opportunities 
  INNER JOIN funders ON funding_opportunities.funder = funders.id 
WHERE funders.id=".$id
```

you forgot to specify which JOIN you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

No need of concatenation if variable is integer

```
$sql = "SELECT funding_opportunities.id 
        FROM funding_opportunities 
        JOIN funders ON funding_opportunities.funder = funders.id 
        WHERE funders.id=$id";
```